# How to compare two inputs and show a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a simple js. Nothing fancy - just show or hide an element only if the inputs have the same value. All before send the form.

```
<form>
 <input type="number" name="some1" id="some1">
 <input type="number" name="some2" id="some2">
 <div id="showhide">The inputs are the same</div>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The result can be something like this.

```
if(#some1(value)==#some2(value)) {
  #showhide.show()
} else {
  #showhide.hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$("#some1, #some2").on("keyup change", function(){
  let firstEl = $("#some1"),
      secondEl = $("#some2"),
      conditionalEl = $("#showhide");
      
  if (firstEl.val() == secondEl.val() ) {
    conditionalEl.show();
  } else {
    conditionalEl.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#showhide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="number" name="some1" id="some1">
 <input type="number" name="some2" id="some2">
 <div id="showhide">The inputs are the same</div>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Glad it helped -- but make sure you mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery should be like this:

```
if($('#some1').val() == $('#some2').val()) {
  $('#showhide').show();
} else {
  $('#showhide').hide();
}
```