# Show DIV if two input values have the same value with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to show a DIV if two inputs have the same value, as already asked here: [How to compare two inputs and show a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346055/how-to-compare-two-inputs-and-show-a-div/48346235)
I can run the code snippet, but when I try it myself it doesn't seem to work. The code is very simple, yet I don't see why the DIV isn't showing when the two values are matching:

```js
$("#some1, #some2").on("keyup change", function(){
  let firstEl = $("#some1"),
      secondEl = $("#some2"),
      conditionalEl = $("#showhide");
      
  if (firstEl.val() == secondEl.val() ) {
    conditionalEl.show();
  } else {
    conditionalEl.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#showhide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
 <input type="number" name="some1" id="some1">
 <input type="number" name="some2" id="some2">
 <div id="showhide">The inputs are the same</div>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: what happens? maybe you need a document ready wrapper for your jquery code

Comment: The document ready wrapper is indeed what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your key up function is not working, Try this

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function myFunction(vaule){
    let conditionalEl = $('#showhide');
    if ($("#some1").val() == $("#some2").val() ) {
        conditionalEl.show();
    } else {
        conditionalEl.hide();
    }
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="number" name="some1" id="some1" onchange="myFunction()">
<input type="number" name="some2" id="some2" onchange="myFunction()">
<div id="showhide" style="display:none;">The inputs are the same</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please dont recommend inline handlers. the correct way would be to use a jquery document ready event wrapper